# vmdk (Normal, Inaccessible): having to repair invalid header too often

Tags: windows, virtualbox, archlinux, samba, virtual-disk

## My situation

I am using **Virtual Box** to create a virtual machine **with Arch Linux installed**. I use the virtual machine for my own projects: I have all my projects data in this virtual machine so I easily can change from OS or physical computer and instantly have all data available. In this virtual machine, I have installed GitLab, a backup system, SMTP, and **Samba**, among others.

The virtual machine has two SATA virtual hard drives:

- 8 GB dynamic vmdk hard drive split into 2 GB files where the OS is installed.
- **2 TB dynamic vmdk hard drive split into 2 GB files where all my projects data is saved.**

Whether I use my Ubuntu to work with the virtual machine, accessing my files from samba, everything is performing perfectly. The problem comes when I use Windows, **after shutting down my machine properly** (see bash command for this below) **the odds are I get a vmdk header corrupted**. Two out of three times I try to shutdown this problem appears in Windows, I didn't experienced the problem In Ubuntu yet.

This is the command I use for shutting down my Arch, `safe_shutdown.sh`:

```
systemctl stop smbd
umount /mnt/projects
systemctl poweroff
```

#### Forced to use the repairing tool too often

I've tried to shut down the machine from VirtualBox, to only use `systemctl poweroff`, to use ACPI shutdown, to close all processes from task manager, to disconnect samba mapped network drive before shutdown, ... everything. **It all result in the same, having my a vmdk header corrupted and having to use the repairing tool**:

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -R projects.vmdk
```

This tool always says me that has found problems in the disk and all have been repaired. After this the machine works again without major problems, sometimes I find a corrupt file when hashing for consistency and I have to use my backups to restore those files.

#### Desesperation

**I do not really know what to do now. Should I try to move my data to another virtual hard drive format? Resize my virtual hard drive? What logs should I look for?**

## My details

On Windows I use the `5.1.2 r108956` VirtualBox version.

#### Virtual Box error

```
Could not open them medium '[projects.vmdk]` VMDK: inconsistency between grain
table and backup grain table in '[projects.vmdk]' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
```

#### Virtual Box Logs

Since I always repair my machine just after getting the error because I need to use my data constantly I can not provide only the last log but all of them. I have uploaded them to a Google Drive folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzoIZrf3afiGRHo0Y2U5c19OdEE?usp=sharing

#### Samba Configuration

```
[projects]
   comment = projects folder
   path = /mnt/projects
   available = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = no
   writable = yes
   valid users = archuser
   write list = archuser
   browseable = yes
   create mask = 0600
   directory mask = 0700
   public = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use virtualbox 4.x.x version. Scan your drive for bad sectors with `fsck` and `badsectors`. You might have compatibility issues or a corrupted file system.